# Rendering a reply form for an Ancestry Nested Comment by ajax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have nested comments using the ancestry gem. **The challenge I'm facing is how to render a reply form with ajax/jquery underneath the appropriate comment on the same page without being redirect to a 'new' page in order to type up a reply**. The comments are linked to another model called Scoreboard. The appropriate code files with what I have done so far are as follows:

The Scoreboard#show page with the form area:

```
<div class= "comment-section">

  <%= form_for [@scoreboard, @comment], :html => { :id => "new-comment-entry" } do |f| %> 

       <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
       <%= f.text_area :body, class: "comment-field" %>
       <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
       <%= f.submit "Join the discussion...",:data => {:disable_with => "Uploading Comment..."}, class: " comment-button btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= nested_comments @scoreboard.comments.arrange(:order => :created_at) %>
 </div>
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
<div class=" comment-div"> 
 <p> Posted by <%= link_to "#{comment.user.name}", comment.user %>
   <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
 </p>
 <div class="comment-body" id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
  <%= comment.body %>
  <%= link_to "Reply", new_scoreboard_comment_path(@scoreboard, comment, parent_id: comment.id), remote: true %> |
  <%= link_to "Delete", scoreboard_comment_path(@scoreboard, comment), :data => {:confirm => 'Delete Message?'}, method: :delete %>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Comment Controller New & Create methods**

```
def new
 @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
 @comment = @scoreboard.comments.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
 respond_to do |format|
     format.js { render action: "new" }
 end
end



def create
     @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
     @comment = @scoreboard.comments.new comment_params
     respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to scoreboard_url(@comment.scoreboard_id) }
      else
       format.html  { 
        redirect_to scoreboard_url(@comment.scoreboard_id)
        flash[:success] = 'Comment must be less than 140 characters'
       }
      end
     end
end
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$("#comment-<%=@comment.parent_id %>").after("<%= j render "reply_form");
```

**_reply_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@scoreboard, @comment] do |f| %> 
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <%= f.text_area :body, class: "comment-field" %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>   
        <%= f.submit "Reply", class: " comment-button btn btn-primary" %>               
<% end %>
```

This is just my take on how it's supposed to happen and clearly I'm doing something wrong because in development I get the following error:

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 114ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:6:in `new'
```

I am open to different approaches if available. Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
Including the nested_comments helper method if it could be causing the trouble:

```
def nested_comments(comments) 
  comments.map do |comment, sub_comment|
    render(comment) + content_tag(:div, nested_comments(sub_comment), class:  "nested_messages")
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

Comment: in `Scoreboard#show`: change the code of form to: `<%= form_for [@scoreboard, @comment], :html => { :id => "new-comment-entry" }, js: true do |f| %>` and try again.

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Well, unknown format error is happening from where ever you're making this call to Comments#new method from your view. Just change that form code to have `js: true` option so that it requests the methods as js instead of html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

```
<%= link_to "Reply", new_scoreboard_comment_path(@scoreboard, comment, parent_id: comment.id), remote: true %>
```

Change it to

```
<%= link_to "Reply", new_scoreboard_comment_path(@scoreboard, comment, parent_id: comment.id, js: true), remote: true %>
```

Also, I think your `new.js.erb` has syntax error. Should be:

```
$("#comment-<%=@comment.parent_id %>").after("<%= j render('reply_form', scoreboard: @scoreboard, comment: @comment %>");
```

Change first line of reply_form to this:

```
<%= form_for [scoreboard, comment] do |f| %>
```

Comment: With your suggestion, the log reads: `Processing by CommentsController#new as 
  Parameters: {"js"=>"true", "parent_id"=>"148", "scoreboard_id"=>"67"}` however, the error is still the same which is `(ActionController::UnknownFormat): app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in "new"` For some reason, it's just not accepting .js as a format. Could it be my **nested_comments** helper method?

Comment: Then could you remove the entire `respond_to` block and see what happens?

Comment: Yes! It worked. It seems the respond_to block was interfering with the js: true in the reply link. Thank you very much for the solution. P.S, there is a missing ")" after the `@comment` in `new.js.erb`.